# Why is the output for this None

Tags: python, csv

```
def parse_planets_file(filename):


    # read source file
    with open('exoplanets.csv', 'r') as file:
        data = file.readlines()

    # prepare output dictionary
    output = {}

    # read line by line
    for idx, line in enumerate(data, 0):

        # split columns
        items = line.replace('\n', '').split(',')

        # extract inner dictionary's keys in a list: 'number', orbital_period', 'mass', 'distance', 'year'
        if idx == 0:
            values = [key for key in items[1:]]

        else:

            # add main key to the output dictionary: 'Radial Velocity', 'Imaging', 'Transit'
            if items[0] not in output.keys():
                output[items[0]] = {key : [] for key in values}

            # add value to the inner dictionary
            for jdx, key in enumerate(values, 1):

                # if the value is a valid number, convert it in float
                if items[jdx] != '':
                    output[items[0]][key].append(float(items[jdx]))

    for items in output.items():

        return output
        break

print(parse_planets_file(filename))
```

When I process this code the output is None even though before it was printing just fine
the expected output is:
{"Radial Velocity" : {"number":[1,1,1], "orbital_period":[269.3, 874.774, 763.0], "mass":[7.1, 2.21, 2.6], "distance":[77.4, 56.95, 19.84], "year":[2006.0, 2008.0, 2011.0] } , 
  "Transit" : {"number":[1,1,1], "orbital_period":[1.5089557, 1.7429935, 4.2568], "mass":[], "distance":[200.0, 680.0], "year":[2008.0, 2008.0, 2008.0] }}

with additional values not included

Comment: probably `with open('exoplanets.csv', 'r') as file:` should be `with open(filename, 'r') as file:`, no?

Comment: I'd suggest to read about the `csv` module. ( https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#module-csv )
Parsing a csv file by yourself is almost never a good idea. Most selfwritten CSV parsers break when some funny strings occur.

Comment: It would also be good if you post the first few lines of one csv file into your question, so that we see what you try to parse.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ff4G_m8XQ8GdAJTdswEGEjDKK1t_QTnuItDx_zYquxc/edit?usp=sharing this is the file in spreadsheet format.

Comment: when I exchange the print line for print(output) it seems to be working however how do I manage to make it work by calling on the definition

Comment: as an aside `[key for key in items[1:]]` is an overwrought way of writing `items[1:]`

Comment: you want to group results by method?

Comment: yes. is there a way to sort the method alphabetically